# Read a text file ignoring comments

Tags: c

**REQUIREMENT**

I have a txt file which looks like this.

```
START:
#INCLUDE "INC1.txt" 
#INCLUDE "INC2.txt"
END
```

When i run my program it should include the contents of the include files and dump in a file. After dumping it looks like this.

```
START:
<Contents of INC1.txt>
<Contents of INC2.txt>
END:
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem I face is if the user gives the includes in comments(/**/) I should not dump those contents.

Eg, Input file will be like this.

```
START:
#INCLUDE "INC1.txt"
/******#INCLUDE "INC2.txt"****
This is a test message*******/
END:
```

And the dump should be like this.

```
START:
<Contents of INC1.txt>
/******#INCLUDE "INC2.txt"****
This is a test message*******/
END:
```

Is there any easy way to ignore the comments. I have to support only multi-line comments(/**/)?

Kindly provide your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you just use your compiler's preprocessor (i.e., `cc -E` ?)

Comment: The best way to handle text processing is to use scripts. I would recomment to use PERL script to implement your requirement with few lines of code. However if you want to implement this in C you have to write your own function or you can use some predefined features of compiler to remove comments in the input file you are processing.

Comment: Do the comments always start and end at the start and end of a line? Or can the sequence `/*` appear inside *data* as well? Should the hard return at the end of the comment end line be removed? Is it possible a comment starts but does not end? (And in that case, should it "continue" into the next file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file in character by character, and keep track of the current character and the previous. character. When the previous character is `/` and the current one is `*` stop copying the previous character to output, and don't start until the characters are `*` and `/`.

Or use a regular expression. There are probably C libraries for that, although `sed` will probably do it with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use string manipulation, set a flag on finding "/*" and if flag is set do as you want in case of comment, and on find "*/" reset flag, setting flag should be prior to string manipulation, it should be like
1 flag setting or reseting
2 if flag set handle it in the way of comment
3 else your desired way....

Answer (score 0):

use gcc with --save-temps option, you will find .i files without comment ...probably that can met a solution for you.
Thanks, Jain